# Accessing a wrapper class from a Helper class

Tags: apex, wrapper-class

I'm trying to access a wrapper class from a helper class.

MyHelper:

```
public with sharing class MyHelper {

    public class someWrapper {

        public Opportunity  someOpportunity {get; set;}
        public Boolean      someBoolean     {get; set;}

        public someWrapper(Opportunity opp){

            someOpportunity = opp;
            someBoolean = true;

        }

    }

}
```

I tried to get access to my `someWrapper` from `MyHelper` but getting this error

> Invalid type: helper.someWrapper

Here is how I have tried:

ControllerExtension:

```
Opportunity  o = new Opportunity()l
MyHelper helper = new MyHelper();
for(Opportunity o : [select...])
{ 
    helper.someWrapper = new helper.someWrapper(o); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes are static, meaning there is only ever a single instance of a class definition. This means that you must refer to the class using its fully qualified name:

```
MyHelper.someWrapper = new MyHelper.someWrapper(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create an instance of wrapper class object then use

```
Opportunity  o = new Opportunity();
MyHelper.someWrapper wrapperObj = new MyHelper.someOpportunity(o);
```

ie: you need a variable 'wrapperObj' to instantiate to.

If  class MyHelper has an object of wrapper as in

```
public with sharing class MyHelper {
    someWrapper someWrapperObj {get; set;}

    public class someWrapper {
       public Opportunity  someOpportunity {get; set;}
       ....
       ....
   }
}
```

Then in controller you could use

```
Opportunity  o = new Opportunity();
MyHelper helper = new MyHelper();
for(Opportunity o : [select...])
{ 
    helper.someWrapperObj = new MyHelper.someWrapper(o); 
}
```